# В чем разница между Master, Slave и Secondary DNS?

Tags: dns

Вляпался тут и зарегил домен на nic.ru, а у них DNS-хостинг платный. Я в этом не бум-бум.Подскажите какой выбрать способ на маленький срок. Мне нужно просто привязать домен к левому хостингу.

nic.ru предлагают выбрать два тарифа DNS-master Primary+Secondary(1 зона, 75 записей) и Secondary(1 зона). Насколько я успел понять, то для перенаправления нужно вносить на ДНС запись А. Раз на Secondary не указано количество записей, то никаких нужных мне записей вносить я не смогу. Получается Secondary мне будет бесполезный?

Answer (score 1):

Если обратить внимание на заголовок в вопросе, то вот такой небольшой ликбез:

- Master(ведущий) сервер на котором мы меняем записи
- Slave(ведомый) - сервер на котором записи периодически обновляются с помощью запросов AXFR к мастеру (соответственно на мастере должен быть разрешен AXFR для зоны)
- Primary/Secondary вообще-то не бывают в этом контексте (в NS записи нет приоритетов) обычно это сервера ns1.[domain.com] ns2.[domain.com]  которые выбираются циклом (round-robin) , с другой стороны есть общепринятый контекст когда выражение primary/secondary dns server имеет смысл - это сервера, которые являются рекурсивными для какой-то машины (записи в resolv.conf).

Так-же, Master или Slave могут быть не включены в записи NS, (slave обычно включены всё-же). Пример - веб панель управляет днс и держит мастер зону, а в NS прописаны только Slave сервера, такая конфигурация позволяет снизить нагрузку с управляющих структур.

Answer (score 0):

Любой хостинг-провайдер (если только ты не собираешься хоститься на своем домашнем/рабочем компе с белым IP) предоставляет NS для доменов, размещенных у него. Так что не парься, прочитай внимательно письмо от хостера и впиши нужные NS сервера в соответствующие поля на nic.ru

Comment: И да, многие серьезные и-нет провайдеры предоставляют услуги NS для домашних пользователей

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно просто привязать домен к левому хостингу.

Берете у "левого" хостера их адреса DNS-серверов и вписываете в настройках домена nic.ru.